# How much DocumentDB is suitable for saving application logs?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-cosmosdb

I want to save logs and traces if my bulky , big enterprise app in DocumentDB.

so that those logs not only help developer to troubleshoot  issues in production but also helps Business takes critical data driven decisions.

For such scenario does Mongo DB or Azure Doc DB suits ?

Comment: Abhi - honestly I don't understand your question: "does NOSQL or Azure Doc DB suits?" What does this mean? NoSQL is an umbrella term representing non-relational databases in general. DocumentDB is a document database (vs key/value, column, graph). Nobody can really tell you the absolute right way to store your logs. It's all about how you want to store things, and more importantly how you'll want to retrieve your log data.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone - this isn't the place to be recommending logging products and instrumentation products (you pitched two products in two comments). It's not even clear what the question is - as it stands, it's unanswerable. Even assuming the OP is just asking for a recommendation, it's off-topic as opinion-based (or even asking for a tool recommendation, which is also off topic).

Comment: @DavidMakogon, you are correct. I'll delete the comments. I have a tendency to want to help. Most of the time, I'm recommending something open source but in both of those cases, they are paid services so that makes it doubly bad. Sorry, I'll be more cautious in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *right* answer to this question - only opinions.

Here are some tradeoffs you may want to consider:

Pros:

- Document-oriented databases, like DocumentDB, are schema-agnostic. This means the logging data's schema is dictated solely by the application. In other words, you can store log output without having to manage schema updates between both the application and database and keeping those models in sync (low friction).
- DocumentDB automatically indexes every property in every document (record). This can speed up your ability to query off arbitrary attributes when debugging... which in turn, can reduce your time-to-mitigate when troubleshooting high-severity incidents.

Cons:

- When compared to storing logs as blobs in a blob store... DocumentDB can look fairly expensive as a log store. You are paying a premium to able to easily index and quickly query off of the data you are storing. You will want to make sure you are getting value out of what you are paying for.

As the comments above suggested, [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) is an umbrella term that which encapsulates key-value store, column-oriented databases, document-oriented databases, graph databases, etc. I'd recommend taking a quick look at the differences between various database categories and understand the differences.

As with any project (logging or otherwise)... You should evaluate the tradeoffs you are making when picking between technologies. An important aspect to software engineering is making the right tradeoffs, and not checking feature tickboxes for the sake of checkboxes.